Line-spacing in lists
In my document I want 1.5 spacing between the lines. However, in my lists I don't see the 1.5. It seems that it's still 1.0 (single spacing).
This is my code:
\documentclass[a4paper, dutch, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}           % Use this package to include images
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}         % A library of many standard math expressions
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=3.5cm,rmargin=3.5cm]{geometry}% Sets 1in margins. 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}           % Creates headers and footers
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}    %This package give custom labels to a list
\usepackage{babel}[dutch]
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\setlist{itemsep=6pt}
  \setcounter{section}{4}
  \title{Hoofdstuk 4}
  \date{}
  \newcommand{\loga}[1]{{}^{#1}\!\log}
  \newcommand{\suma}[2]{\sum\limits_{#1}^{#2}}
  \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
  \newcommand{\ee}{\mathrm{e}}
\setlength{\mathindent}{1cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.]
        \item $y=\sin 2x\to y'=2\cos 2x\to y''=-4\sin2x\to y'''=-8\cos 2x$
        $\sin 2x\approx 0+\dfrac{2\cos0}{1!}x+\dfrac{-4\sin0}{2!}x^2+\dfrac{-8\cos0}{3!}x^3=2x-\frac43x^3$
        \item $y=\ee^x+\cos x\to y'=\ee^x-\sin x\to y''=\ee^x-\cos x\to y'''=\ee^x+\sin x$ \\
        $\ee ^x+\cos x\approx 2+\dfrac{1}{1!}x+\dfrac{0}{2!}x^2+\dfrac{1}{3!}x^3=2+x+\frac16x^3 $
        \item $y=x-\sin x\to y'=1-\cos x\to y''=\sin x\to y'''=\cos x$\\
        $x-\sin x\approx 0+\dfrac{0}{1!}x+\dfrac{0}{2!}x^2+\dfrac{1}{3!}x^3=\frac16x^3$
        \item $y=\sqrt{1+x}-\frac12x\to y'=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x+1}}-\frac12\to y''=-\dfrac{1}{4(x+1)\sqrt{x+1}}\to \\y'''=\dfrac{3}{8(x+1)^2\sqrt{x+1}}$\\
        $\sqrt{1+x}-\frac12x\approx 1+\dfrac{0}{1!}x+\dfrac{-\frac14}{2!}x^2+\dfrac{\frac38}{3!}x^3=1-\frac18x^2+\frac{1}{16}x^3$
        \item $y=1-\cos x\to y'=\sin x\to y''=\cos x\to y'''=-\sin x$\\
        $1-\cos x\approx 0+\dfrac{0}{1!}x+\dfrac{1}{2!}x^2+\dfrac{0}{3!}x^3=\frac12x^2$
        \item $y=\arcsin x\to y'=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\to y''=\dfrac{x}{(1-x^2)\sqrt{1-x^2}}\to \\y'''=\dfrac{1}{(1-x^2)\sqrt{1-x^2}}+\dfrac{5x^2}{2(1-x^2)^2\sqrt{1-x^2}}$\\
        $\arcsin x\approx 0+\dfrac{1}{1!}x+\dfrac{0}{2!}x^2+\dfrac{1}{3!}x^3=x+\frac16x^3$
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}

Thanks!

Welcome to TeX SE. Irrelevent to the problem but your loaded enumitem twice and you don't need enumerate since enumitem superseeded it.

Thanks. It was due to trying some things with the packages. Overseen it.

I took the liberty to rearrange your code in a compilable one and to remove the package that are repeated. Next time, try to make your code as small as possible by removing package that are irrelevent to the matter at hand.
